# Cheerio Web Scape: No Line Break Between Tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, cheerio, nightmare

When I use `$('.episode-title')` the output I get is

`Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 02Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 01`

The Output I want is
`Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 02 \n Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 01`

How Do I Do this?

### ***Edit 1*** My Code

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = `https://subsplease.org/shows/otona-no-bouguya-san-s2/`
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

// Request making using nightmare
nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .wait('body')
  .wait('label.episode-title')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
  .end()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(getData(response));
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });


let getData = html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    let title = $('.episode-title').text()
    console.log(title)
}
```

### ***Edit 2*** JSON

```
{
    "episodes": [ 
       {
        "title": "Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 01",
        "torrents": [
            {
                "resolution": "1080p",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            },
            {
                "resolution": "720p",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            },            
            {
                "resolution": "sd",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            }
            
        ]
       }, 
       {
        "title": "Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 02",
        "torrents": [
            {
                "resolution": "1080p",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            },
            {
                "resolution": "720p",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            },            
            {
                "resolution": "sd",
                "magnet": "url",
                "torrent": "url"
            }
            
        ]
       } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: What output? The Cheerio selector code that you wrote does not generate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two elements with class `.episode-title` you should use `map` or `forEach`. Here's one:

```
let titles = $('.episode-title').map((i, el) => $(el).text()).get();
console.log(titles);

// => ["Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 02", "Otona no Bouguya-san S2 — 01"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one use:

```
$('.episode-title').first().text()
```